# Mail - \r\n characters visible in recieved email

Tags: php, jquery, phpmailer, wp-mail

I'm sending a test email to myself which contain values inserted into a form.

I recieve the email, but the "formating" is all wierd and `\r\n` is visible. I tried `%0D%0A` and `</br>` (although didn't specify that it would be an HTML) as well and it was also visible. I also tried `PHP_EOL`.

Additionally, I also recieve a 2cnd email right after the 1st one, but it contains only a fraction of the previous form.

1st email:

```
Date of arrival: 19-02-2021%0D%0A
                                                                        Date of departure: 27-02-2021%0D%0A
                                                                        Room selected:  Room 01 %0D%0A
                                                                        Name: dread%0D%0A
                                                                        Surname: Zxy%0D%0A
                                                                        Email myemail@gmail.com%0D%0A
                                                                        Phone number: 012345678
```

2cnd email:

```
Date of arrival: 19-02-2021%0D%0A
                                                                        Date of departure: 26-02-2021%0D%0A
```

*Edit* I just noticed that the 2cnd email does not contain the same date of departure as the 1st one. I have no idea why that is, so I'll add the jQuery code as well.

I would be greatful if anyone has any idea how to resolve this.

The code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $arrivalDate = $_POST['arrivalDate'];
        $departureDate = $_POST['departureDate'];
        $room = $_POST['room'];
        $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $tel = $_POST['tel'];
                    
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = 'Reservation';
        $body = 'Date of arrival: '.$arrivalDate.'\r\n
                Date of departure: '.$departureDate.'\r\n
                Room selected: '.$room.'\r\n
                Name: '.$user_name.'\r\n
                Surname: '.$surname.'\r\n
                Email '.$email.'\r\n
                Phone number: '.$tel;
                            
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body );
        echo "Sent!";
    }
?>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#arrivalDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 'dateToday',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function (date) {
            $("#departureDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
        }
    });
    $("#departureDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
});
```

Comment: What is that `%0D%0A` junk doing in your string? Just use `\r\n` inside double quotes.

Comment: Edited. This is the "content" i have for the email. Are you saying it should be `"\r\n"`?

Comment: They're *outside* the string. This code makes no sense to me. Remember, **double quotes**, not singles.

Comment: all right, so your saying `'string displayed' . $variable . "\r\n"`

Comment: No, I've added a better example in my answer. You're making a mess of things doing it that way with concatenation and two different quoting styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP there's a world of difference between single and double quotes:

```php
<?php echo('\r\n'); ?>
```

This produces `\r\n`, literally, as text, whereas this:

```php
<?php echo("\r\n"); ?>
```

Actually emits CRLF, as you want.

Single quoted strings *are not interpolated*, and do not support control characters like `\r`. Double quoted strings do.

That being said, there's a better way of expressing this:

```php
<?php
$body = implode("\r\n", [
  "Date of arrival: $arrivalDate",
  "Date of departure: $departureDate",
  "Room selected: $room",
  "Name: $user_name",
  "Surname: $surname",
  "Email $email",
  "Phone number: $tel"
]);
```

Let the string interpolation do the work for you, then use `implode()` to connect them together.

In your code you're not only putting in `\r\n` but with the string spanning multiple lines you're including at least an LF as well, another extraneous `\n`.

That means:

```
<?php

echo('I love
newlines!');
?>
```

Already contains a newline.

Comment: All right. Thank you. the `"\r\n"` with double quotes did solve it, but I might use your anwser. If I would want to add additional string to the body (lets say something like: Thank you for registering. You have room1 reserved from xy to yx, would implode also work on it)?

I'll accept the anwser in 2 mins. need to wait...

Comment: You can always add additional lines after that as necessary, this format is quite open-ended.

Comment: Yea, just continue the string. Sorry a bit tired. I actually have a question about that. How can I add characters directly next to variables. something like `"price: €$price_per night"`?

Comment: You can add whatever you want, [PHP strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) are fairly flexible.

Comment: sorry, wrong example. I meant something like `"Price for night for $room: €$price_per_night"`. Im talking about the **:** next to `$room`.

Comment: The docs explain in more detail, but generally only "variable-like" components are absorbed. `$room!` is fine. `$rooms` if you wanted the `s` separate is not, you'd have to do `{$room}s`.